# Angular select value with change method

Tags: angular, select, bootstrap-4

I have one select component and one function to get the value of the select.

The problem is the value is undefined. When I used angular material it worked, but now I am using bootstrap, and stopped working.

Html:

```html
<select  class="custom-select" (change)="updatePlayerRole($event,i)" style="text-align-last: center;" >
  <option selected disabled value>Role</option>
  <option value="top">Top</option>
  <option value="jungle">
    <img src="/assets/Images/waiting/jungle.png" height="20" width="20"/>Jungle
  </option>
  <option value="mid">
    <img src="/assets/Images/waiting/mid.png" height="20" width="20"/>Mid
  </option>
  <option value="bot">
    <img src="/assets/Images/waiting/bot.png" height="20" width="20"/>Bot
  </option>
  <option value="support">
    <img src="/assets/Images/waiting/support.png" height="20" width="20"/>Support
  </option>
  <option value="fill">
    <img src="/assets/Images/waiting/fill.png" height="20" width="20"/>Fill
  </option>
</select>
```

```js
updatePlayerRole(value,i){
    console.log(value.value);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(i);
    this.team[i].role = value.value;
    this.checkIfFormIsCompleted();
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Or the change method is not being used correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps to start with:

1. Create a string array for your options within your component.ts file.
2. loop over the array in your html to create your options.
3. pass in the `$event.target.value` to your `(change)="updatePlayerRole($event.target.value)"`

simple example below:

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
  options: string[] = [
    'top',
    'jungle',
    'mid',
    'bot',
    'support',
    'fill'
  ];

  selectedOption: string = '';

  updatePlayerRole(value: string) {
    console.log(value);
    this.selectedOption = value;
  }

}
```

then in your component.html

```
<select (change)="updatePlayerRole($event.target.value,i)">
  <option disabled>Please Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{ option }} 
  </option>
</select>
    
<p>Selected Option: <strong>{{selectedOption || 'nothing is selected'}}</strong></p>
```

That will get you a string value in the `updatePlayerRole()` method within your component.

Here is a stackblitz example for you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxvygr